# How do I remove the spacing between two texts in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm actually trying to clone an Insta page. How do I remove the space between two texts inside a column in Flutter pointed with a green arrow in the screenshot? The upper text "6,667" had to be bold so I had to separate it with "Posts".

Please see the screenshot here:

[image: Please see the screenshot here:]

Comment: Please post your code inline, too.

Answer (score 4):

for line spacing use height property in `TextStyle`

```
Text('Hello World', style: TextStyle(height: 1.0  // change this as you want
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the \n in \nPosts Text Widget

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your 2nd Text("\n Posts");

Please, remove the \n from the text and it will be okay